# In Edge chromium browser Tiny MCE javascript rich text editor (v3.5.10) is throwing error in MVC 4 web application while its working fine in IE11

Tags: javascript, runtime-error, tinymce, microsoft-edge, disabled-input

We are using Tiny MCE javascript rich text editor (v3.5.10) in our ASP.Net MVC4 web application.
This editor was working fine in IE11. But in the edge chromium browser this editor is throwing exceptions.

Some issues to begin with are:

1. Create a new proposal document – Here the HDF page is not behaving correctly and some tinyMCE editor controls are not becoming visible, some are not editable probably due to editor control initialization issues in Edge chromium browser.
2. Edit existing proposal information page - editor controls are not becoming editable probably due to initialization issues in Edge chromium browser.

The following are the errors we see in the developer console-

[This image contains details of javascript error we are getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uqkkg.png)
The other error we see is –
[This is another js error we are getting in console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XAgLg.png)

Also we are attaching some code files for your quick reference.
We can also setup a meeting to discuss issues.
Please let us know your suitable time to connect.

Answer (score 0):

Edge Chromium was released in Jan 2020 whereas TinyMCE 3.5 has not been updated since October 2014 so it would not be surprising that TinyMCE 3.5 would have issues with a browser that did not exist at the time it was released.

All that being said your two errors show issues with jquery and not TinyMCE so can you explain why you believe that stack trace related to TinyMCE?

Answer (score 0):

We can see that you are using the **Tiny MCE (v3.5.10)**, if we try to refer to the official Tiny MCE v3 document for [browser compatibility](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs-3x/extras/TinyMCE3x@Browser_compatiblity/) then we can notice that the **Edge browser** is not listed there. The Edge Chromium browser was also not exist at that time.

So it can be possible that **Tiny MCE v3** is not fully compatible with the **Edge Chromium** browser and because of this reason you are getting an errors in the Edge Chromium browser.

In that case, I suggest you make a tests with the latest stable version (at present: 5.2.2) of the **Tiny MCE**.

If we check the [browser compatibility](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/general-configuration-guide/system-requirements/#supportedwebbrowsers) document for the latest Tiny MCE then we can see that the **Edge browser** is listed there.

So moving to the latest version of the Tiny MCE editor can help to fix the issue.

I also suggest you to contact the Tiny MCE Support and take their opinion for the said issue.

It can really help to narrow down the issue.